# How to test void method?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

```
public void checkAlreadyUsedOrValidHealthDashBoardToken(ServiceCode serviceCode) {
    if(serviceCode.getHealthDashBoardToken().isEmpty()) {
        return;
    } else if(isAlreadyUsedHealthDashBoardToken(serviceCode)) {
        throw new GlobalException(ResponseType.SERVICE_ALREADY_USED_HEALTH_DASHBOARD_TOKEN);
    } else if(!isValidHealthDashBoardToken(serviceCode)) {
        throw new GlobalException(ResponseType.SERVICE_NOT_VALID_HEALTH_DASHBOARD_TOKEN);
}
}

@Test(expected = GlobalException.class)
public void checkAlreadyUsedOrValidHealthDashBoardTokenTest() {
    List<ServiceCode> serviceCodeList = new ArrayList<ServiceCode>();
    serviceCodeList.add(serviceCode);

    Mockito.when(serviceManageMapper.selectServiceByHashBoardToken((ServiceCode)notNull())).thenReturn(serviceCodeList);
    // execute test
}
```

I just want to test void method. how can I execute the test? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you want to test it should have a return type. But then if you want to test in this manner then,

```
@Test
public void checkAlreadyUsedOrValidHealthDashBoardTokenTest()
{
    <Enter prerequisite codes>
    int flag=0;
    try
    {
        checkAlreadyUsedOrValidHealthDashBoardToken(serviceCode);
    }
    catch(GlobalException ge)
    {
        if(GlobalException Response Type is SERVICE_ALREADY_USED_HEALTH_DASHBOARD_TOKEN)
        {
            falg=1;
        }
        else if(GlobalException Response Type is SERVICE_NOT_VALID_HEALTH_DASHBOARD_TOKEN)
        {
            flag=2;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        assertEquals(flag,0/1/2);
    }

}
```

Enter three types of data and check 0,1 and 2 states.
**This is not at all good coding. But then it might be something you want.**
NB. Some codes are roughly written as logic above enter proper code on the basis of your class implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think that the function name is a bit too long, but whatever.

As for your question, what do you mean by test? Debug? If so, I would scatter print statements throughout the code to test it.